# XAML to HTML Conversion - WPF RichTextBox

Tags: c#, html, wpf, xaml

I have the problem where i have a WPF RichTextBox, and i'm extracting its XAML code and saving it to a txt file. When i copy paste the XAML code generated to a XAMLtoHTML converter like this http://blogs.msdn.com/wpfsdk/archive/2006/05/25/606317.aspx , some error must be occuring as i'm always getting a blank result!

If i write `test` in the RichTextBox i get the following XAML:

`<Section xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xml:space="preserve" TextAlignment="Left" LineHeight="Auto" IsHyphenationEnabled="False" xml:lang="en-us" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" NumberSubstitution.CultureSource="Text" NumberSubstitution.Substitution="AsCulture" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" FontSize="12" Foreground="#FF000000" Typography.StandardLigatures="True" Typography.ContextualLigatures="True" Typography.DiscretionaryLigatures="False" Typography.HistoricalLigatures="False" Typography.AnnotationAlternates="0" Typography.ContextualAlternates="True" Typography.HistoricalForms="False" Typography.Kerning="True" Typography.CapitalSpacing="False" Typography.CaseSensitiveForms="False" Typography.StylisticSet1="False" Typography.StylisticSet2="False" Typography.StylisticSet3="False" Typography.StylisticSet4="False" Typography.StylisticSet5="False" Typography.StylisticSet6="False" Typography.StylisticSet7="False" Typography.StylisticSet8="False" Typography.StylisticSet9="False" Typography.StylisticSet10="False" Typography.StylisticSet11="False" Typography.StylisticSet12="False" Typography.StylisticSet13="False" Typography.StylisticSet14="False" Typography.StylisticSet15="False" Typography.StylisticSet16="False" Typography.StylisticSet17="False" Typography.StylisticSet18="False" Typography.StylisticSet19="False" Typography.StylisticSet20="False" Typography.Fraction="Normal" Typography.SlashedZero="False" Typography.MathematicalGreek="False" Typography.EastAsianExpertForms="False" Typography.Variants="Normal" Typography.Capitals="Normal" Typography.NumeralStyle="Normal" Typography.NumeralAlignment="Normal" Typography.EastAsianWidths="Normal" Typography.EastAsianLanguage="Normal" Typography.StandardSwashes="0" Typography.ContextualSwashes="0" Typography.StylisticAlternates="0"><Paragraph><Run>test</Run></Paragraph></Section>`

pleaseee help!! Any Ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

XamlToHtml expects a `FlowDocument` and RichTextBox is giving you a `Section`.  The Section is a perfectly valid containing the text you need, but XamlToHtml won't process anything except a full `FlowDocument`.

Wrap the Section in a `<FlowDocument>` element and you should be good to go.  You'll have to adjust the namespace (xmlns) of course, so I suggest you manipulate it as an `XmlDocument` instead of as text.

Comment: This was so helpful, thank you so much! It completely resolved my issue with appending a <FlowDocument> at the beginning and </FlowDocument> at the end