# XAML to HTML converter

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0, mvvm

I have a requirement to save emails written in a RichTextBox to a database. Obviously, I would like to persist the formatting to the DB and send out HTML emails. However, this requires converting XAML to HTML which will be stored and then converting back if they are reloaded from the DB.

I have tried out the XAMLtoHTML converter. The problem I am getting is that the converter only works partially. It sets up all the formatting correctly in HTML but the text part is missing. I have followed this post:: [XAML to HTML Conversion - WPF RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609694/xaml-to-html-conversion-wpf-richtextbox) and had the same error but adding the  tags didnt solve the problem.

Has anyone got experience with XAML to HTML conversions?  Thanks

Comment: Sounds like your *real problem* is converting rich text to html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using this free HTML Editor for silverlight instead. [Html RichTextArea Control (Silverlight 4 Only)](http://www.vectorlight.net/silverlight/controls/html_richtextarea.aspx).

You then load and save HTML and not bother with Xaml at all.  Just be careful with the fontsizes, last time I looked only px sizes worked, pt sizes were not supported.  You may want to fiddle with the samples font drop down so that the actual value is 1.33 the displayed size.

Comment: Thanks Anthony - looks like it does what I need. Will give it a go.